# how to use the same function inside two or more Buttons in the onCreate() method

Tags: android

Im new in android and i do not know many things. I have a problem making a function inside two ore more buttons and place it in the **onCreate** method. For example:

```
public class gameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int num = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //the two buttons from layout
        Button tl = findViewById(R.id.buttonTL);
        Button tm = findViewById(R.id.buttonTM);

        //the void function that the buttons may use
        void printChar(){
            //do domething
        }
            

        //click listeners to above Buttons
        tl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tl.setClickable(false);
                num++;
                //function i want to call
                printChar();
            }
        });

        tm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tm.setClickable(false);
                num++;\
                //function i want to call
                printChar();
            }
        });            
    }
}
```

All i want to do is to make the printChar(); function inside the onCreate(), to make all the buttons use this, and not write the same code inside each button again and again..

Comment: The onCreate is a method, you can't declare a method inside another method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the OP comments :

```
public class gameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int num = 0;
    private Button tl, tm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //the two buttons from layout
        tl = findViewById(R.id.buttonTL);
        tm = findViewById(R.id.buttonTM);


        //click listeners to above Buttons
        tl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tl.setClickable(false);
                num++;
                //function i want to call
                printChar();
            }
        });

        tm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tm.setClickable(false);
                num++;\
                //function i want to call
                printChar();
            }
        });            
    }


    void printChar(){
            //do domething
            String textTl = tl.getText().ToString();
           String textTm = tm.getText().ToString();

        }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to define another method inside another method in java, But will this be fine to you if you define the method just somewhere outside of `onCreate` but still inside the activity?

```
public class gameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int num = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //the two buttons from layout
        Button tl = findViewById(R.id.buttonTL);
        Button tm = findViewById(R.id.buttonTM);



        //click listeners to above Buttons
        tl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tl.setClickable(false);
                num++;
                //function i want to call
                printChar(num);
            }
        });

        tm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tm.setClickable(false);
                num++;
                //function i want to call
                printChar(num);
            }
        });
    }

    //the void function that the buttons may use
    void printChar(int num){
        Log.d("PrintNum", "Num: " + num);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's hard for me, because i want to take the other button's text and make some calculation inside the function. I dont know if you understand me..

Comment: i want to: getText() of all the buttons and make the same calculation inside the printChar each time some of the buttons are pressed.

Comment: May i highly discourage the "calculate with text"-concept? Instead, you should have a viewModel holding the value as a flow, like val `button1Value = MutableStateFlow(0)`.  You'll then observe the flow on the view-layer (and set the button-text). On click you'll call `viewModel.onButton1Clicked()` which then will do `buttonValue.update { it + 1}`.

Comment: @AlexandrosGkainta you need to learn the Java basic first and then start making Android apps, you can easily declare your variables (button, text..) in the global (above the onCreate method) then you can use them as you like